# Find customers who spent above a certain amount

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to use VBA to search through a list of customer names and the amount they have spent (in columns A & B respectively), and return a results list with the names (& corresponding amount) of those who have spent more than $500, in two other columns in the same sheet, say columns D & E.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: show us, please, what have you tried.

Comment: I'm curious to know: why would you like to use VBA here? Doing an autofilter and then copying and pasting would be much simpler.

Comment: or use the autofilter copy and paste in VBA and not use a loop.  That would be the fastest way.

Answer (score 0):

A for loop like this within a subroutine would work:

```
i = 1
For j = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(1))
    If Cells(j, 2) > 500 Then Cells(i, 3) = Cells(j, 1): i = i + 1
Next j
```

This prints just the names but using the same logic you can also print the corresponding numbers. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-looping suggestion.  Should  be about as fast as you can get

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim lr As Long


Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheet1
    lr = WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Columns(1))
    .Range("A1:B" & lr).AutoFilter
    .Range("$A$1:$B" & lr).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=">500"
    .Range("$A$1:$B" & lr).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy .Range("D1")

    .Range("A1:B" & lr).AutoFilter
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Assumes the work needs to happen on sheet1 and you can refine the "how the last row is calculated" part to be a bit more robust, but this should get you close...